# Django Template Arithmetic

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my template, I am looping through a list, trying to  make a two-column layout.  Because of the desired two-column layout, the markup I need to write in the for loop is dependent on whether `forloop.counter0` is even or odd.  If I had the full power of Python in the template language, determining the parity of `forloop.counter0` would be trivial, but unfortunately that is not the case.  How can I test whether `forloop.counter0` is even or odd using the Django template language, or just as good, is there another way I could get elements in the list to display alternatively in the left and right columns?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [divisibleby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) filter with `forloop.counter`:

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" %}even{% else %}odd{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should probably use [`cycle`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) here instead. As for your question, there is a filter called [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby).

The philosophy behind Django's template system is to avoid doing any serious logic in the template. Thus they only provide tools to do fairly basic calculations for cases like drawing grids etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use [cycle template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#cycle):