# Django operator inside template for loop

Tags: django, for-loop

I want to add the number of starts that is the division of two IntegerField in django. So I am trying to do:

```
{% for i (object_list.0.score//object_list.0.num_votes) %}
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for i in "x"|rjust:(object_list.0.score//object_list.0.num_votes) %}
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
{% endfor %}
```

But seems is not allow to do operations inside for loop. Is that true? Any workaround?

Comment: Try this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#widthratio

Comment: You have to use a template filter or write a method on that model class. `def average_score(self): return self.score // self.num_votes`

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7571677/394647):

> The philosophy behind Django's template system is to avoid doing any serious logic in the template. Thus they only provide tools to do fairly basic calculations for cases like drawing grids etc.

If you consider you still need to do this operation on template side you might want to create your own [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-mathfilters](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfilters) to make basic arithmetic operations (division, subtracting, multiplying, etc) in templates.

You also can calculate the value in your view and pass it to the template.

If you need this value on many different pages you should define a filter to do the division and use it where you need it in the templates.